# How to connect to SOAP server from Java and run my server builtin methods/services?

Tags: java, php, zend-framework

How can i connect from Java to my SOAP server and get the givemeSmile() methods? This does not work in Java, i was trying URLConnection but i think not possible with that?.

My question is: Is there any SOAP client libraries?

Php (sender):

```
class Zend_Controller_Action
{
  /**
   * Client module - always works
   */
  public static function indexAction()
  {
    $client = new Zend_SOAP_Clnt('http://www.test.gov/index/server');
    $result = $client->givemeSmile('test');
    var_dump($result);  // output: hehehe test
    exit;
  }

  /**
   * Server module - works
   */
  public static function serverAction()
  {
    require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Soap.php';
    if ( $if_mannually_url_is_open===true ){
      $server = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
    }else{
      $server = new Zend_Soap_Server("http://www.test.gov/index/server");
    }
    $server->setClass('My_Model_Soap')->forJava();
    $server->handle()->render();
  }

}
```

Java (receiver):

```
  URL url = new URL(getServer(1)); // to WSDL/SOAP link
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
  wr.write(data);
  wr.flush();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  String line;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
  {
       line.givemeSmile(); // expected output: hehehe test
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the apache axis 2 to quickly create a soap client. The soap messages are usually xml format and SOAP uses a WSDL file as an interface description.

[Here is a quick introduction](http://wso2.org/library/290) including a 5-liner to implement a SOAP client and get a result from a received SOAP massage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library to send HTTP requests. Usage example is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/HttppostmethodExample.htm).

But it's low-level solution, you have to implement lots of details by hand, choose it only if your application is not very big. If this approach doesn't suit you, you should use some SOAP client library like Axis2 or [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/) (example [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html)).